# Text input loses focus with useState event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ace-editor

I am building a React component that uses react-ace to input markdown that is rendered in real time. Every time I type a letter, the letter gets entered and then focus immediately changes and I can no longer type without clicking back into the editor.

Here is the code for the component:

```js
export default function Edit(props) {

  let placeHolder = props.isNew ? md : ""; 
  let urlParams = useParams();
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  let action;
  let actionName;

  const [contents, setContents] = useState(placeHolder);
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const [idToken, setIdToken] = useState(null)

  Auth.currentSession().then((s) => setIdToken(s.idToken.jwtToken))

  if (!props.isNew) {
    useEffect(() => {
      getPost(urlParams.postId)
        .then(post => {
          setContents(post.contents);
          setPost(post);
        });   
    }, [props.postId]);

    action = () => {
      updatePost(post, contents, idToken)
        .then(() => navigate('/'))
    }

    actionName = "Update"
  }
  else {
    action = () => {
      newPost(contents, idToken)
        .then(() => navigate('/'))
    }

    actionName = "Create"
  }


  return (
  <Authenticator hideSignUp={true}>
    <PageContainer single={true}>
      <ActionMenu action={action} cancel={() => navigate('/')}>{actionName}</ActionMenu>
      <ContentContainer>
        <AceEditor
          mode="markdown"
          theme="monokai"
          onChange={v => {setContents(v)}}
          name="editor"
          height="100%"
          width="60vw"
          value={contents}
        />
        <MarkdownWrapper>{contents}</MarkdownWrapper>
      </ContentContainer>
    </PageContainer>
  </Authenticator>
  )
}
```

I noticed that removing the `setContents()` call from the onChange prop of the AceEditor component stops this from happening which leads me to believe that this component is being re-rendered every time I type, causing focus to change. I tried removing `contents` from the value prop in case that was causing the re-render, but nothing changed.

How can I stop this component from re-rendering whenever `setContents()` is called?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-goldstine-lttou1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @user4980215 I can't get that sandbox to work. It spits out an error and when I fix it the page is just blank.

Comment: I add one more import and checked in another browser. It doesn't loose the focus in a simple case. Maybe problem is higher in hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing two issues:

1. You are making an api call here: `Auth.currentSession().then((s) => setIdToken(s.idToken.jwtToken))` outside of a `useEffect`. For the token, it would seem you would want to only call that once when the component mounts, so you want to pass an empty array as the second argument. For more info: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/fetching-api-using-useeffect-hook-in-react-js-7b9b34e427ca
2. You're calling `useEffect` in an if statement which is against the rules of hooks. https://ru.react.js.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Try fixing these issues and seeing if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you for calling this out, I will definitely fix those issues. As a quick test I just removed all code outside of the `return()` call and the issue still happens.